# How to use blazor event handlers in code constructed html string?

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

I am trying to build a change event into a html table in a blazor-server-side app. When using @onchange in an input element or a select element in the razor section it works fine.
The problem is that I build the table dynamically using asp code to construct the html string (since the table is filled from a database). In this dynamically constructed table the change event doesn't work. Here is some code:

```
public string ConvertDataSetToHTMLTable(DataTable dt)
{
    string html = "<table>";
    //add header row
    html += "<tr>";
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        html += "<th>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th> ";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
    
    //add rows
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            html += "<td>"; 
            html += "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form - control\" @onchange=\"Alert\" value=\"" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\" >";

        }
        html += "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
```

In the razor section I call

```
    <div>
        @((MarkupString)ConvertDataSetToHTMLTable(dt))
    </div>
```

If I understand this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026281/can-markupstring-property-convert-a-string-of-custom-component-into-html-element) right, `MarkupString` cannot convert razor components to HTML.

Any idea how to workaround this issue?

Comment: What about `@Html.Raw(ConvertDataSetToHTMLTable(dt))` Works in Razor. Or write the entire table in Razor instead of code.

Comment: @Html is not recognized. Do I have to install some package?

Comment: That is part of MVC. But maybe Blazor works differently.