# How can bootstrap 5 tooltip title attribute use a blazor render fragment in .net 8?

Tags: .net, blazor, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I am wanting to use a bootstrap 5 tooltip on a button, and I want the content of the tooltip to be a blazor component in .net 8. I tried a RenderFragment, but that does not work.

Bootstrap has a "title" attribute where the markup should be added see example below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
    Tooltip on top
</button>
```

In a static blazor component, I wanted to do this:

```
<div @ref="@Element"
     style="@Style"
     @attributes="Attributes"
     class="@GetCssClass()" 
     data-bs-toggle="tooltip" 
     data-bs-placement=@(Placement.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
     title=@TooltipContent
     data-bs-html="true"
     disabled="@Disabled">

     @ChildContent

 </div>
```

The TooltipContent would be a razor component, and NOT raw html. The issue is converting a blazor component into raw html, and then pass the raw html into the bootstrap title= attribute.

Notice that I would like to generate the html from the "TooltipContent" into the "title" attribute.

The result is the "title" attribute is missing from the final render, probably because it is empty.

How can a blazor renderfragment provide bootstrap "title" the raw html needed to render the tooltip? Is there a different way to get his working for a bootstrap tooltip?

FYI: Shoelace has slots, and renderfragment works well, but bootstrap is using an attribute for content which seems to be an issue.

The example

Comment: [Polite] Do you understand what a `RenderFragment` is?  See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/8.0-rc2/src/Components/Components/src/RenderFragment.cs

Comment: Yes. "Represents a segment of UI content, implemented as a delegate that writes the content to a RenderTreeBuilder." a delhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.renderfragment?view=aspnetcore-7.0 . I am looking for a way to have razor components generate html that the bootstrap title attribute will use.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>"` i.e. some static markup or more complex.  Looking at it I can't at the moment see how to shoehorn in a `RenderFragment`.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps there are other options for taking a blazor component, converting into html, and feeding it into the bootstrap title= attribute.

Comment: I may be missing the point, but why not use `MarkupString`?

Comment: Have a look at this.  It's new in Net8.  I'm using it in a static site builder - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-components-outside-of-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: MarkupString is for raw html. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026281/can-markupstring-property-convert-a-string-of-custom-component-into-html-element . It will not render a blazor component. I will make that acceptance critera more explicit.